# How to format something like "6/23/2014 12:04:32 AM" with strptime

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I am dealing with a dataframe whose one column is class of factor and looks like

```
"6/23/2014  12:04:32 AM".
```

I want to convert it into Date or "POSIXlt" and "POSIXct" type with:

```
strptime(date, format=...)
```

But I have failed to formalize the format here after trying several times. Can someone give a hand?

My trying was with `"%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strptime("6/23/2014  12:04:32 AM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

## "2014-06-23 00:04:32 IDT"
```

From documentation of `%p`

> %p AM/PM indicator in the locale. Used in conjunction with %I and not
>   with %H. An empty string in some locales (and the behaviour is
>   undefined if used for input in such a locale).

Comment: Thank you David @David Arenburg, that was helpful. I am changing to format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") but still return NaN to me. Also I have tried format="%m/%d/%Y%t%I:%M:%S%t%p")

Comment: Can you provide `head(dput(date))`?